# Only one MobX-State-Tree flow active at a time

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have a MobX-State-Tree (MST) store with an action that is a `flow` that fetches some items asynchronously. This action can be called from several places in the app, sometimes even simultaneously, but I only want one `flow` to be active at a time.

Is there any way in MST to return the currently active `flow` if there is one, or create a new one if there isn't?

**Example**

```js
const Thing = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  name: types.string,
});

const ThingStore = types
  .model({
    things: types.array(Thing),
  })
  .actions((self) => ({
    // This action will create a new flow every time it is called.
    fetchThings: flow(function* () {
      const things = yield fetchThings();

      self.things = things;
    }),
  }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a piece of [volatile state](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/volatiles) that keeps a reference to the promise that is returned when calling a `flow`. If a `flow` is already active we return this promise. If not, we create a new `flow` and return that.

**Example**

```js
const Thing = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  name: types.string,
});

const ThingStore = types
  .model({
    things: types.array(Thing),
  })
  .actions((self) => {
    let fetchThingsPromise = null;
    const fetchThings = flow(function* () {
      try {
        const things = yield fetchThings();

        self.things = things;
      } finally {
        fetchThingsPromise = null;
      }
    });

    return {
      fetchThings: function () {
        if (fetchThingsPromise) return fetchThingsPromise;

        fetchThingsPromise = fetchThings.apply(null, arguments);
        return fetchThingsPromise;
      },
    };
  });
```